Example for Effective Java where clone() returns a shallow copy
In Effective Java 3rd edition Joshua Bloch talks about how you should implement clone method in complex objects.
public class SimpleHashtable<K, V> implements Cloneable {
    private Entry<K, V>[] buckets; 
    private int size;

    private static class Entry<K, V> {
        final K key;
        V value;
        Entry<K, V> next;

        Entry(K key, V value, Entry<K, V> next) {
            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;
            this.next = next;
        }

        // Recursively clone the linked list of entries
        Entry<K, V> deepCopy() {
            return new Entry<>(key, value, next == null ? null : next.deepCopy());
        }
    }

    public SimpleHashtable() {
        buckets = new Entry[16]; // Default size
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleHashtable<K, V> clone() {
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            SimpleHashtable<K, V> result = (SimpleHashtable<K, V>) super.clone();
            result.buckets = new Entry[buckets.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < buckets.length; i++) {
                result.buckets[i] = buckets[i] != null ? buckets[i].deepCopy() : null;
            }
            return result;
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            throw new AssertionError();
        }
    }
}

The Entries in the buckets will reference different objects than the original. However, I think that key and value will be references to the same objects as in the original. What if the cloned hash table modifies a value for a given key, then the modification will be reflected in the original. As a result, we really have a shallow copy.
Am I missing something or is the example incorrect?

Yes, the keys and values in the new SimpleHashTable will be the same objects as those in the old one. Why would you assume anything else?

Does he say it's a deep copy? What is the exact relevant quote? By definition this example is not a deep copy.

He does not say the keys and values are deep copies, but I assumed when we clone we never want to share references to mutable objects between a copy and the original.

Who says the keys or values are mutable?  The HashMap can't know, not can it know how to copy the keys and values, which may not use clone or a copy constructor.

I’ve never understood this fascination with clone(). I’ve never used it in 27 years. Never had a use for it.

(If we could somehow strike "deep copy" and "shallow copy" from the IT language, that would IMO be a good thing.  And "clone" too.)

@Oleg - I've never seen a sound (i.e. indisputable) general definition of shallow and deep copying in the context of Java.  It is ... rubbery.

The new hashtable is a "deep copy" in that if you modify it (by adding/removing entries) the original won't change.
Yes, the keys and values are the same objects. You should never modify map keys anyway, because if the hash code changes, the data structure will be invalid. The example is to illustrate cloning a hashtable, not the values too.

If a 'deep copy' is defined as 'if you modify this deep copy, the original will not change', pray tell what a 'shallow copy' is. A copy which, if you modify it, the original also changes? What's the difference between that and a simple duplicated reference then?

@rzwitserloot I read the intention of the example as a shallow copy would share the same buckets array, so adding/removing from the copy will also affect the original. A "deep copy" creates a copy of the internal data structure. The example is deliberately ignoring cloning the keys and values, focusing on what a deep copy means. What if keys or values don't define a clone impl, or can't be copied (eg enums). IMHO there would be too much code noise to code a true complete deep copy without diluting the instructional purpose of the simple example.

My point is simply that the terms 'shallow' and 'deep' have devolved into a meaningless soup here. At best, we can refer to these terms are explaining what some internal implementation detail does. For consumers of this API, what is called 'deep copy' here is a shallow copy, so, extremely confusing. If this is, to an outside observer, not a shallow copy, then what would a shallow copy even look like? A 'deep copy' to an outside observer would be a full and total copy, changing anything would not be visible to the original, no matter how deep, hence 'deep copy'.

Sure, yes, that kind of deep copy is difficult/impossible in java, although the Cloneable interface stuff tries (and mostly fails) to make this possible in java. Translating "X is impossible" to "therefore lets just redefine what X even means" is not a good idea.
